# npm link libreria local dentro de proyecto react

Tags: reactjs, npm

estoy trabajando con una libreria que en realidad es un componente de react (no se puede levantar la libreria por si misma, es necesario instalarla en un proyecto si o si).

La libreria esta ubicada dentro de node_modules del proyecto react. Lo que hago es ejecutar npm link dentro de la carpeta de la libreria luego en el proyecto react simplemente lo importo y lo uso

El problema es que cada vez que hago un cambio en la libreria, no se refleja en el proyecto. Entonces tengo que hacer lo siguiente: 1- volver a hacer npm link en la libreria 2- parar y volver a ejecutar npm start en el proyecto react.

La pregunta entonces es: Como hago para que cada vez que haga cambios en la libreria se refleje automaticamente en el proyecto react?

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Existe una librería llamada `nodemon` la cual se encarga de volver a iniciar tu proyecto si hay cambios lo puedes instalar  de esta manera `npm i nodemon` solo configura cual es tu archivo principal
Aquí te dejo la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)